# Mysql table join consumes too much time

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have two mysql tables

1. Transaction table (300k rows)

   ```
   D_ID    D_Account       D_Account_Type
   ```
2. account details table (50 000 rows)

   ```
   A_ID    A_Card  A_Account   A_Bin   A_Date  A_Update_Date   A_Product
   ```

I am trying to update A_Product in account details table corresponding cell in transaction table i.e. D_Account_Type

I am using below query but it takes too much time.

```
UPDATE tbl_atm_tran p 
JOIN tbl_data a ON p.A_Account = a.D_Account 
SET p.A_Product = a.D_Account_Type
```

Is there any way to reduce the query execution time.

Comment: May be [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33749/sql-update-satement-taking-a-very-long-time-high-disk-usage-for-hours?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) can help.

Comment: Create index on relational columns...p.A_Account = a.D_Account